# How does one convert a binary IPv4 address to 4 octets using the Python3 ipaddress library?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, ipv4, octetstring

I want to use the Python3 library [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_network) to convert a binary IPv4 network address into 4 octets; how would I do that?

**Example:**

```
1100 0000 - 1010 1000 - 0000 0000 - 0000 0000
```

to

```
192.168.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward way, especially not if the input is in such a weird format. Convert each "octat" to decimal:

```
import ipaddress

weird_ip = '1100 0000 - 1010 1000 - 0000 0000 - 0000 0000'
print(ipaddress.IPv4Address('.'.join(str(int(''.join(i.split(' ')), base=2))
                            for i in weird_ip.split(' - '))))
```

Outputs

```
192.168.0.0
```

Comment: I'm fine with straight binary all 32-bits if need be.